# Size of Purussaurus, a giant Miocene crocodylian (2022)

Tags: zoology, phylogenetics, literature, palaeontology

What is the currently accepted size estimates (length and mass) of *Purussurus barsiliensis*? I quote the relevant part in Wikipedia.

From Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purussaurus

> The skull length of the largest known individual of the type species, P. brasiliensis is 1,453 millimetres (57.2 in).[2] It has been estimated that P. brasiliensis reached about 10.3 metres (34 ft) in length, weighing about 5.16 metric tons (5.69 short tons).[2] Another estimate gave a larger size of 12.5 metres (41 ft) in length, ranging from 9.8–15.7 metres (32–52 ft), and 8 metric tons (8.8 short tons) in weight, ranging from 5.6–12.6 metric tons (6.2–13.9 short tons), with a mean daily food intake of 40.6 kilograms (90 lb).[3] It is also likely that Purussaurus reached only 10.9 metres (36 ft) long and 5.6 metric tons (6.2 short tons).[3] A 2022 study estimated a length of 7.6–9.2 metres (25–30 ft) and a mass of 2–6.2 metric tons (2.2–6.8 short tons) using a phylogenetic approach; and a length of 9.2–10 metres (30–33 ft) and mass of 3.9–4.9 metric tons (4.3–5.4 short tons) using a non-phylogenetic approach.[4]

Old estimates were up to 13 meters but more recent ones decreased it to 10.9 and the newest one from 2022 decreased even further:

> A 2022 study estimated a length of 7.6–9.2 metres (25–30 ft) and a mass of 2–6.2 metric tons (2.2–6.8 short tons) using a phylogenetic approach; and a length of 9.2–10 metres (30–33 ft) and mass of 3.9–4.9 metric tons (4.3–5.4 short tons) using a non-phylogenetic approach.[4]

Reference to [4]: Paiva, Ana Laura S.; Godoy, Pedro L.; Souza, Ray B. B.; Klein, Wilfried; Hsiou, Annie S. (2022-08-13). "Body size estimation of Caimaninae specimens from the miocene of South America". Journal of South American Earth Sciences. 118: 103970. Bibcode:2022JSAES.11803970P. doi:10.1016/j.jsames.2022.103970. ISSN 0895-9811. S2CID 251560425.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0895981122002589

Since I don't have access to this paper I ask here few questions:

1. How did they estimate *Purussaurus* size?
2. What is a phylogenetic approach in the context of size estimates? I know phylogenetics is the study of evolutionary "family" trees and cladograms but how it affects size estimates?
3. What is a non-phylogenetic approach in the context of size estimates?
4. Why the two approaches yielded different estimations for *Purussaurus*?
5. Why the 2022 yielded a lower size estimate? Is it based on new fossils?
6. What are the scientifically accepted on *Purussaurus* size, considering the latest studies?

Comment: You are asking a lot of questions in one post, on a site that works better if you limit your question to one question - many of the answers to each of these questions will be full essay style answers in themselves. You will probably be better to break it up into several separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The estimates are based on 4 fossil skulls. As far as I can tell these are not new finds, the wiki link says the largest known skull as 1453 mm, and the largest of the 4 in the JSAES article is 1406 mm. This is probably the same skull measured with two slightly different techniques.

Animals don't just scale up linearly as they get bigger, even in the same species. Younger animals have different proportions from old ones, and different species have different proportions, of course. In particular, the ratio of body length / skull width is different. The 'phylogenetic approach' used in the article in question developed a statistical model for how this ratio varies in the family tree, then estimated the specific ratio for  *Purussaurus*. The details for this approach are given in [another recent article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895981122002589), in case you're able to access that one.

The non-phylogenetic approach estimated the ratio with a linear regression of the full dataset, not weighting for relatedness.

As far as I can tell, the main reason the 2022 study gives smaller estimates of size is their exclusion of data from juveniles from the dataset used to estimate size from skull dimensions. I would have expected juveniles to have a larger head size relative to the rest of their body, but apparently that's not the case.